# Job System, Unity | Native Array of struct containing different types. Error InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, jobs

I am just starting to work with Job System and Burst Compiler(1.4.0) and I have a problem.
I have a structure with arrays of different types. When I try to create a NativeArray out of it, I get an error on startup "**InvalidOperationException: 'Data' used in NativeArray<> must be unmanaged (contain no managed types) and cannot itself be a native container type.**" I don't know what to do, I tried to use native arrays instead of unity arrays, but I still get the same error.
My main task is to pass triangles, vertices and normals to Job to generate a mesh.
The structure is used in another class to return the required parameters

Class:

```
    public class Model
    {
        public List<GameObject> gameObjects;
        public Vector3[] vertices;
        public int[] triangles;
        public Vector2[] uvs;
        public Vector3[] normals;

        public Data GetData()
        {
            return new Data(vertices, triangles, uvs, normals, gameObjects.Count);
        }
    }
```

Structure:

```
public struct Data
    {
        public readonly int gameObjectsCount;
        public readonly Vector3[] vertices;
        public readonly int[] triangles;
        public readonly Vector2[] uvs;
        public readonly Vector3[] normals;

        public Data(Vector3[] _vertices, int[] _triangles, Vector2[] _uvs, Vector3[] _normals, int _gameObjectsCount)
        {
            vertices = _vertices;
            triangles = _triangles;
            uvs = _uvs;
            normals = _normals;
            gameObjectsCount = _gameObjectsCount;
        }
    }
```

The line that cause the error:

```
int length = 10;
NativeArray<Data> _data = new NativeArray<Data>(length, Allocator.Persistent);
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to get around this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I may be wrong as Unity isn't my topic, but, .net arrays are managed and of an undefined size, it's impossible to allocate a native array of undefined size into a struct unless you only allocate a pointer to the external array (which would defeat the purpose of native arrays as those would point to managed arrays). Usually when structures like yours are used for native interop you must use [fixed-size buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers)

Comment: It turns out that need to pass a fixed buffer to the structure constructor?

Comment: Not to the structure constructor, you must declare the arrays inside your structure as fixed size buffers, in this way the system can allocate a concrete memory span for the items. Each element in a native array must be of the same size, so variable size arrays can't be used. Check the link on my previous comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work as it only works with primitive types :(

Comment: Structs like vectors are primitive types...

Comment: When I try to make a fixed buffer out of a vector I get the error "Fixed size buffer type must be one of the following: bool, byte, short, int, long, char, sbyte, ushort, uint, ulong, float or double"

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you're right...

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what you're doing wrong. You're using a managed array in your struct which is unsupported and defeats the purpose of the thread safety guaranteed by Unity's job system, as the array is a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on the idea of using NativeArray, instead I used NativeStream. Maybe it will be useful for someone

```
private void AddToStream(int index, Data data)
    {
        writer.BeginForEachIndex(index);

        writer.Write(data.elementsCount);

        writer.Write(data.vertices.Length);
        foreach (float3 vertex in Extestions.Vector3ToFloat3(data.vertices))
        {
            writer.Write(vertex);
        }

        writer.Write(data.triangles.Length);
        foreach (int triangle in data.triangles)
        {
            writer.Write(triangle);
        }

        writer.Write(data.uvs.Length);
        foreach (float2 vertex in Extestions.Vector2ToFloat2(data.uvs))
        {
            writer.Write(vertex);
        }

        writer.Write(data.normals.Length);
        foreach (float3 normal in Extestions.Vector3ToFloat3(data.normals))
        {
            writer.Write(normal);
        }

        writer.EndForEachIndex();
    }
    public Data GetLookUpFromStream(int index)
    {
        NativeStream.Reader reader = stream.AsReader();

        reader.BeginForEachIndex(index);

        var vertices = new List<Vector3>();
        var triangles = new List<int>();
        var uvs = new List<Vector2>();
        var normals = new List<Vector3>();

        var elementsCount = reader.Read<int>();
        var verticesLength = reader.Read<int>();

        for (int i = 0;i < verticesLength; i++)
        {
            vertices.Add(reader.Read<float3>());
        }

        var trianglesLength = reader.Read<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < trianglesLength; i++)
        {
            triangles.Add(reader.Read<int>());
        }

        var uvsLength = reader.Read<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < uvsLength; i++)
        {
            uvs.Add(reader.Read<float2>());
        }

        var normalsLength = reader.Read<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < normalsLength; i++)
        {
            normals.Add(reader.Read<float3>());
        }

        reader.EndForEachIndex();

        Data data = new Data(vertices.ToArray(), triangles.ToArray(),uvs.ToArray(),normals.ToArray(), elementsCount);
        data.Print();

        return data;
    }
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question (you) asked.